# What color paint would most blend into trees?

Tags: painting

I did a project that ended with surplus: an 18ft pallet and 3/4G of exterior premium weatherproof white primer. So, of course, I painted the pallet with the weatherproof paint and I'm going to have it upright with cables holding it to a tree and it's going to be a climbing toy for my kids. But then I realized a white thing like that wouldn't look very nice among trees.
So I'm looking for a color that would make it just blend in with the trees. I've already primed it white so I cannot go back on that but this is premium weatherproof BM primer so it's already weatherproof. So this coat is primarily for aesthetics. Even if it peeled a little that would be OK. I just want to aesthetically blend it into the trees.
I'm not looking to really paint tree bark textures or anything fancy. Just one color that blends in.

Comment: your question does not make much sense ... you can see the trees, people on the internet cannot see the trees, yet you ask people on the internet what color would blend with the trees ... it seems like there is something that you are not saying

Comment: Depends what kind of trees you have.

Comment: The way shipping pallets are nailed together is not meant to hold their pieces together under great force.  You should add screws to all the joints to help keep it together if people are climbing on it.  Also, I'm voting to close because design/aesthetic questions are not encouraged here.  You could ask how to make it *safer* ... I would tell you it's a terrible idea.  Chemically treated wood, full of cracks and splinters, barely held together with short nails .... not for kids to climb on!

Comment: It's the Northeast. Sorry I forgot how different trees look in e.g. AZ than in New England.
Also I guess this question didn't go over so well in a few other ways.

Comment: @Jay613. Thx for the info about it possibly being treated. That had never crossed my mind since they are only used once and I see a lot of suggestions for reusing pallets for arts and crafts, furniture even hanging gardens. Now I did a little research and it says PT would have the IPPC logo on it. But now that I've already primed it I can't check for the markings. And even if I would knowingly use treated wood (which I wouldn't) then why did I work so hard to weatherproof it. Pretty messed up.

Answer (score 1):

**Given the question's added single color requirement:**
Light brown is probably the best all year round color. White would blend best in winter, but a green in summer; brown is typically seen year round. You can go to pretty much any home improvement store and take home sample swatches of various browns to compare to your trees if you want as close as a match as possible for blending.

**The original question didn't specify a single color and this was the answer I posted.**

What about camouflage?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EFhA-b1nzVw

A variety (4 or 5 different shades) of greens and browns will work well; maybe it could be a weekend project for the family.

You simply draw irregular blobs on cardboard and cut out the blob for the remainder to be a stencil you will use to spray paint the object.

Comment: Yeah that would be ideal. But even if I did that I'd want one gallon of some not so expensive paint to be the background then we'd see how much effort we want to put into variety colors. So what color background? (Tree's are rarely really brown, they're some kind of baise / brown right?)

Comment: trees come in all different colours, perhaps take some bark samples to the paint store.

Comment: @Jasen Now that is thinking outside the box. It would be worth the look on their face even if the machine couldn't ID it.

Comment: Camouflage paint is difficult to find. And most people spoil it by stirring it all up before painting...

Comment: @Tim they have the same issue with tartan paint... :)

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell without photo of trees in question, but maybe you could use the Disney "vanishing green"? Its a color blend designed to make things blend (sic) into the surroundings. I do not know if it works only for urban environments, or would also help with your particular case.

Comment: I'd never heard of "go away green" before. That's fascinating that a color could be so much less noticeable that Disney uses it to hide things.